# How can I graft Wilderness of Mirrors onto Gumshoe?

Tags: gumshoe

Or specifically, how can I adapt *Wilderness of Mirrors* Mission Planning/Obtaining Information/complication/Trust system onto the resource management/clue finding *Gumshoe* system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have a bit of bear of time because the WOM resources are rather rationed on time (adversity chips, etc, etc) whereas the Gumshoe resources are rationed by use.

I think you could certainly graft complications and trust into gumshoe. Trust would recharge investigative abilities whenever the players did something to screw each other over.

Complications could either be immediate like in Wom, where they are only announced once the ops has actually introduced them, giving a bene or a investigative abilities point or as Gumshoe is not so Dirty, per say as WOM, the game master could start throwing out false facts and freebie investigative pts (this doesn't mesh so well with Gumshoes, you find all the clues business, but hey such is the nature of hybrids).

Answer (score 2):

You need Night's Black Agents! One way to model it is to have a group Intel pool, that any player can use for spends - but as they do so, it gets smaller and smaller, so players have an incentive to use it before their rivals do.